# Access a NumericUpDown Value from a different class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a project to make an Alarm Clock. When the set alarm time is equal to the current time, a popup form with the buttons "Snooze" and "OK" should be displayed.
The "Snooze" button should set the value of a NumericUpDown Box to

```
Minutes.Value = Minutes.Value + 5;
```

However, I have no idea how to import the NumericUpDown value to the new class so that I can change and return it to the original/main class.

Comment: Make your Snooze form expose an event called OnSnooze. Clients (your main form) can subscribe to this event to be notified when the user Snoozes and do whatever they need to do with their internal controls. No need to _import_ anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve has pointed, you can expose one event and subscribe to it, but if you're not familiar with `events` an easy way can be:

Declare a property in your PopUp dialog that returns the selected increment.

```
public int Increment { get {return SelectedIncrement; } }
```

Show the dialog and increase the value:

```
DialogResult res = YourDialog.ShowModal();

if (res == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    Minutes.Value += YourDialog.Increment;
}
```

Comment: Nice. You just forgot to mention that I have to assign a DialogResult to my custom button, from my custom form. But all went well, thank you